# How do I fix hung indexing of Messages?

Tags: messages, spotlight

I've always assumed that all of the indexing on a Mac is done via Spotlight.  But
when I hit ⌘-Space and start typing, the "indexing" bar does not appear at this point.  `mdutil -s /` shows that it is on.  But when I go to `Messages` and do a find, I get some results but then at the bottom of the search results is:

```
More results will be shown once Messages
finishes indexing.
[INTERNAL1 Reason: No Recorded Reason. Indexed 3000 /
65414 records. Version 21. Last Reindex Completion Date
2022-03-18 08:31:34 +0000
```

I've tried erasing the Spotlight index.  I'll try that again.  And I've looked in `Activity Monitor` for `mdworker` with a high CPU but the two processes are idle.  So, I'm wondering if the indexing `Messages` is using might be separate?

In any case, how do I get `Messages` to finish indexing?

[Using macOS 12.3]